# Sould I keep NSManagedObjectModel in a property for later use?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

Since I embeded fetch request in my model.xcdatamodeld, I need an instance of NSManagedObjectModel to get the fetch request from it. So I can do :

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [managedObjectModel fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:requestTemplateName
                  substitutionVariables:substitutionDictionary];
```

**My question is about the managedObjectModel. Should I keep it in a property to reuse ? or should I call mergedModelFromBundles when needed ?**

I don't know the cost of a call of '[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil]' in terms of memory/rapidity. The the name "mergeModelFrom" make me think that this hide some operations that could lead to bad bad performance if executed for each request in my application. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple templates do this

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DiscussIt" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

This way the creation is only done if `managedObjectModel` == `nil`, which is what you want.

Notice this is written in the getter so you don't need to worry about remembering to instantiate `managedObjectModel` as this is taken care of and lazily instantiated when you actually try to access it.